# How to disable physicsBody of a SKSpriteNode if node is hidden?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to hide some enemies before I need them. But the problem is - hero is interacting with their physicsBidies anyway. I'm trying to do it like so:

```
self.cat.hidden = true

if self.cat.hidden == false {
self.hero.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Cat.rawValue
self.hero.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Cat.rawValue
}

if self.cat.hidden {
    self.cat.physicsBody = nil
}else{
self.cat.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: cat.texture, size: self.cat.size)
self.cat.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
self.cat.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Cat.rawValue
self.cat.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Hero.rawValue
self.cat.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Hero.rawValue
}
//in didBeginContact
if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Cat.rawValue && self.cat.hidden == false || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Cat.rawValue && self.cat.hidden == false) {
       eatenByCat()
    }

//in update
if (self.score >= 10) {
      self.cat.hidden = false
                }
```

I turned on skView.showsPhysics and physic bodies of enemies are still there and my hero is contacting them. Why? I want player to think that there are new enemies appearing when he has a certain score, but in code they are spawning randomly, I just don't want to show them right away. So I need my hero to ignore them for a while.

Comment: I suggest you generate the cats only when they are needed in the game.

Comment: Due to some circumstances it's not an option for me.

Comment: Did you try setting the `contactTestBitMask` and `collisionBitMask` to 0.

Comment: Yes I did. I doesn't work, hero still able to contact with them

Comment: Try setting the `categoryBitMask` to 0 for the hidden cats

Answer (score -3):

inside update() method

```
 if sprite.hidden {

sprite.physicsBody = nil

}
```